# PHP __SoapCall issue

Tags: php, soap

I have a simple service using `php` and `Soap`

There's a function named **getPrice** in my `SOAP SERVER`

This is ***getPrice :***

```
    function getPrice($productISBN, $param)
    {

        return $productISBN;
    }

$kks = new SoapServer(null, array('uri' => "urn://my/webservice/shop"));

    $kks->addFunction( array(
                    'getPrice',
                    'reserveProduct',
                    'inquiryPostPrice',
                    'registerPostOrder'

                 ) );

    $kks->addFunction(SOAP_FUNCTIONS_ALL);

$kks->handle();
```

and this is my client file -This is in `/kkc` folder :

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
      'location' => "http://example.com/webservice/kks/shop.php",
      'uri'      => "urn://my/webservice/shop"
    ) );

var_dump( $client->__soapCall('getPrice', array(123456789, $param) ) );

//$param is a string
```

but I'll get this error in client :

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Internal Server
 Error in /example.com/webservice/kkc/client.php:28 Stack trace:
 #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('__soapCall('getPrice', Array)
 #2 {main}   thrown in /example.com/public_html/webservice/kkc/client.php on line 28
```

I have two other files like this and there's everything is fine...

Would you please let me know what's wrong here?

**Thanks in Advance**